# How do I setup a guest network with Time Capsule

Tags: macos, wifi, time-capsule

Since I bought my Time Capsule (only a few months ago) the AirPort Utility app has been changed/upgraded and the instructions that I got with the product on how to setup a guest wifi network no longer apply or make any sense..  So my question is how do I setup a guest wifi with apple's current software: Airport Utility v 6.0 on OS 10.7.4

Answer (score 2):

The in app help will guide you if you search for guest or "set up a guest network"

The settings are under wireless with a simple check mark to enable a guest network.

Here is the most relevant steps from the help included with Airport Utility:

```
To set up a guest network, the Apple wireless device must be set up to share its public IP address using DHCP and NAT.

1. Open AirPort Utility, located in the Utilities folder in the Applications folder.
2. Select the wireless device on which you want to set up a guest network, and then click Edit.
3. Click Wireless, and then select Enable Guest Network.
4. Give the guest network a name.
5. Choose None, WPA/WPA2 Personal, or WPA 2 Personal from the Guest Network Security pop-up menu, and then type a password for the guest network.
```

Comment: step 3 does not work, there is no "Enable Guest Network" option displayed after recent updates..

Comment: Be sure your base station is fully updated. Call support with the serial number to be 100% sure yours is simultaneous dual- band. You did verify it's not in bridge mode and has NAT+DHCP.